# SQL Execution in Azure taking a very long time

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I'm using ASP.NET Core 1.1.

The following is the query which takes most time and causes all this trouble:

C#

```
    List<Message> messages =await _context.Messages.Where(m => m.UserId.Equals(_userManager.GetUserId(User)))
    .Select(m => new Message { ID = m.ID, DateTime = m.DateTime, Text = m.Text }).ToListAsync();
```

SQL

```
SELECT [m].[ID], [m].[DateTime], [m].[Text] FROM [Messages] AS [m] WHERE [m].[UserId] = @__GetUserId_0
```

Execution plan statistics:
[image: Execution plan statistics]

My website become very slow and not responsive, sometimes showing errors.

Comment: Your execution plan shows an index scan of nearly 500,000 rows. Seems like you're doing a complete scan, instead of hitting the index. But without seeing your indexes, it's a bit difficult to tell.

Comment: How many rows does the query return? How long does the query take in SSMS (for all rows to appear?)

Comment: @DavidMakogon That's an interesting point, what would cause skipping the index?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It depends on user, I'd say 12 rows on average. I don't know the exact time but something like 10 seconds.

Comment: Adding an index on UserID will reduce that 10 seconds (assuming it uses the index or isn't already skipping it for some reason)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have created all required indices but I think that it's skipping.. do you have a guess on why is it skipping?

Comment: Which indexes are 'required indexes'? Did you create an index on UserID or not?

Comment: what is your `GetUserId` doing ?

Comment: even if you have index on the query shown,showing nearly 44K rows on website makes it slow..how are you showing the rows

Comment: This conversation should be moved to [chat](chat.stackoverflow.com) vs having a discussion in comments.

Comment: The clustered index scan returns 44K rows, but the final select probably doesn't (I also misunderstood that).

Comment: @DavidMakogon if your first reply as an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in comments: Your execution plan shows an index scan of nearly 500,000 rows. Seems like you're doing a complete scan, instead of hitting the index.

I suspect adding an index on `UserId` would resolve this issue, as that's the only field used in your `WHERE` clause.